# How to solve a problem time expired in javasrcipt

Tags: javascript, json, google-sheets

I am trying to send data to **Google Sheet** in my mobile application.

The data arrives well but the code does not return the result quickly
here is my JavaScript code.

The problem is that it takes a long time (around 360s) to return the result

> it's ok

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/177kUZc61U8huVsq2OcGsiF2OGdPCSxMjkoh2C4KIWPM/edit#gid=0");
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Info');

function doGet(e) {
    var action = e.parameter.action;

    if (action == 'UpdateInfo') {

        //return UpdateInfo(e);
    }
}

function doPost(e) {
    var action = e.parameter.action;

    if (action == 'UpdateInfo') {
        return UpdateInfo(e);
    }
}

function UpdateInfo(e) {
    var values = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var email = e.parameter.email;
    var password = e.parameter.password;
    //var date = sheet.getRange('A').getValues();//new Date();
    var name = e.parameter.name; ///Item1
    var lname = e.parameter.lname;
    var itemuserImage = e.parameter.itemuserImage;
    var region = e.parameter.region;
    var provaince = e.parameter.provaince;
    var ecole = e.parameter.ecole;
    var Unite = e.parameter.unite;
    var niveau = e.parameter.niveau;
    //var flag = 0;
    var lr = sheet.getLastRow();

    for (var i = 1; i <= lr; i++) {
        var IDuser = sheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();

        //row[1];
        var shetemail=sheet.getRange(i,2).getValue();
        var shetpassword=sheet.getRange(i,3).getValue();

        if (shetpassword==password && shetemail==email ) {
            sheet.getRange(i,4).setValue(name);
            // sheet.getRange(i,5).setValue(lname);
            //row[2];
            ///zoydghnmayad sheet.getRange(i,7).setValue(region);
            //row[4];
            sheet.getRange(i,8).setValue(provaince);
            //row[5];
            sheet.getRange(i,9).setValue(ecole);
            //row[5];
            sheet.getRange(i,10).setValue(Unite);
            //row[5];
            sheet.getRange(i,11).setValue(niveau);
            //row[5];
            var dropbox="USERSIMAGE prof";
            var folder, folders=DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);
            if (folders.hasNext()) {
                folder=folders.next();
            } else {
                folder=DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
            }
            var fileName=IDuser+"profile_pic.jpg";
            var contentType="image/jpg" , bytes=Utilities.base64Decode(itemuserImage), blob=Utilities.newBlob(bytes, contentType,fileName);
            var file=folder.createFile(blob);
file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK,DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
            var fileIdumage=file.getId();
            var fileUrlumage="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=" +fileIdumage; sheet.getRange(i,6).setValue(fileUrlumage);
            //row[5];
            return ContentService.createTextOutput("its ok").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
        }
    } ///thiya loop
}
```

Comment: What is the size of your image? Could you try to upload smalled files (like a text file) and see if that also takes a long time? Thanks ! :D

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure.But do you check your image size of "profile_pic.jpg".
In my experience,if you capture the profile image using mobile app camera,the image size is extremely large.It will take ages to upload the image if you forget to compress it(no need such high HD image for profile, and compression is neccesary).

As a matter of that,please double check size of the image you were uploading.And please do not forget to compress it if it occupy too much space.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will look this way